# neo4jrestclient index results returns Iterable instead of node/url?

Tags: python, indexing, neo4j, neo4j.py

I'm trying to follow the docs
http://readthedocs.org/docs/neo4j-rest-client/en/latest/indices.html

I expect the index query to return a node, but it returns an "Iterable: Node" instead:

```
db = GraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data")
playerIndex = db.nodes.indexes.get("index1")
playerNode = db.nodes.create(player_id = "Homer")
playerIndex.add("player_id", "Homer", playerNode)
print playerIndex["player_id"]["Homer"], "\n", playerNode
```

prints:

```
<Neo4j Iterable: Node>
<Neo4j Node: http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/157>
```

How can I get neo4jrestclient index query results to return a Node like the 2nd line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index lookups can return more than one node so in this case, it's returning an iterator. To get the next item in the iterator, do .next():

```
print playerIndex["player_id"]["Homer"].next(), "\n", playerNode
```

See: https://github.com/versae/neo4j-rest-client/blob/master/neo4jrestclient/iterable.py

Answer (score 3):

As @espeed has pointed, call `.next()` will give you the next node in the index.
You can also iterate over the iterator:

```
for node in playerIndex["player_id"]["Homer"]:
    print node, "\n", playerNode
```

Or just get all the results in the iterator using the slice `[:]`:

```
print playerIndex["player_id"]["Homer"][:], "\n", playerNode
```

The client behaves in this way because any index query always returns a list of elements, even if there is only one. So, the best weay to handle this is using an iterator with lazy load.